# How to come up with time complexity of backtracking problem?

Tags: python, time-complexity, backtracking

Given a list of lists, print list of lists where each list in the output is a combination of elements from the input lists.

For example:
I/P -> [['a','b'],['c'],['d','e','f']]

o/p -> ['a','c','d'], ['a','c','e'], ['a','c','f'], ['b','c','d'], ['b','c','e'], ['b','c','f']

I have come up with the backtracking solution. Below is the code. However, i have difficulty in finding its time complexity. I think it's O(m^n), where m is the length of longest list in the given list of lists and n is the length of the given list. Is it right? How to find time complexity of backtracking problems like these?

```
def helper(lists, low, high, temp):
    if len(temp) == high:
        print temp
    for i in range(low, high):
        for j in range(len(lists[i])):
            helper(lists, i+1, high, temp+[lists[i][j]])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [['a','b'],['c'],['d','e','f']]
    helper(l, 0, len(l), [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Towards the complexity question:

If there are `K` lists each of length `n_k`, for `k = 1,...,K`, then the total number lists you need to output is `n_1 * n_2 * ... * n_K` (assuming order does not matter). Your bound clearly holds and is sharp when `n_1 = n_2 = ... = n_k`.

Alternatively, we can let `N = n_1 + ... + n_k` be the size of the disjoint union of input lists, and look for a bound in terms of `N`. For a fixed `N`, the worst case occurs when `n_1 == n_2` etc., and we get `O((N/k)^k)`. Maximizing over `k`, we find that `k=N/e` where `e` the Euler's number. So, we have `O(e^(1/e)^N) ~ O(1.44^N)`.

As LeopardShark suggests, you can look up the `itertools` implementation of product for reference. It will not improve the asymptotic speed, but it will be more space efficient due to lazy returns.

A more tidy Python implementation could be as follows:

```
def custom_product(lsts):
    buf = [[]]
    for lst in lsts:
        buf = [b + [x] for b in buf for x in lst]
    return buf
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are effectively doing is re-implementing `itertools.product()`.

Your code above is equivalent to

```py
import itertools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    l = [['a','b'],['c'],['d','e','f']]
    l2 = itertools.product(*l)
    for x in l2:
        print(list(x))
```

I think the time complexity of both solutions is O(number of lists × product of lengths of lists), but `itertools.product()` will be much faster, being written in C and properly optimised.